# How to select SCOPE_IDENTITY() using Microsoft SQL Driver in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a special MSSQL statement which I use to retrieve the identity of a specified row that either already exists or else INSERTs and then retrieves that identity. This SQL appears to work great in SQL Management Studio as well as a couple of my .NET C# apps.

Unfortunately, I've been asked to use PHP for this particular task and I am having great difficulty trying to use PHP and the official Microsoft SQL driver.

The statement isn't returning an ID after the INSERT (or if it is, I'm not able to retrieve it). Could somebody please see where and if I'm going wrong?

I'm using PHP 5.3.23 with Microsoft SQL Driver 3.0. Here is my code:

```
$sql = ''
        . 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE sAMAccountName = ?) = 0 '
        . 'BEGIN '
        . 'INSERT INTO users (role, sAMAccountName, fullName) '
        . 'VALUES (1, ?, ?) '
        . 'SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() '
        . 'END '
        . 'ELSE SELECT id FROM users WHERE sAMAccountName = ?';
$params = array($requester, $requester, $fullName, $requester);
$query = $this->SqlQuery($sql, $params);

function SqlQuery($sql, array $params) {
    $conn = $this->SqlConnection(null, null, null, null); // x4 null = use default connection options
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($query) {
        sqlsrv_fetch($query);
        echo 'Result: ' . sqlsrv_get_field($query, 0); // This should return an ID regardless
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }
}
```

Here is the result HTML (No Result):

```
Result:
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with T-SQL so please bear with me if I'm asking nonsense but... Is that complete self-contained code? It's all a single line, no separator between e.g. INSERT and SELECT. Looks weird that it runs at all :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The only thing in SQL that is line-dependent is the line comment (`--`).  Other than that everything in SQL (and T-SQL) including multiple statements, can be written without any line breaks.  And traditionally statement separators (`;`) have not been necessary, though they are required for the new statement keywords (`WITH`, `RECEIVE`, ..), and will be required in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your query.

Your `INSERT` statement actually returns something: an empty recordset plus the message "(1 row affected)". SSMS just concatenates all the recordsets, but in sqlsrv you have to explicitly advance to the second recordset to see your `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` result. By turning off the rowcount feature the uninteresting results set is quashed, and it will do what you want.

Comment: Useful to know and would explain why my statement appeared to work in SSMS and in even in a C# app. Still, even without `SET NOCOUNT ON;` I should still see the result of `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` if I advanced to the next record set using `sqlsrv_next_result($query); sqlsrv_fetch($query); $id = sqlsrv_get_field($query, 0);`? I'm almost certain I tried that and all I got was "false".

Comment: So have you tried `SET NOCOUNT ON`, and did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is an option for you but:  I would change the SQL statement into a stored procedure, and include the return of the identity.  Once a stored procedure make these changes to the statement

```
'SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() '
```

to

```
'SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id'
```

Then within PHP you should be able to access the id as a datatable.  Stored procedures will return data as a datatable, not sure on the PHP side, I'm a .NET person

If you need help with convert the statement into a stored proc, let me know.

EDIT:
Assuming that sAMAccountName is the primary key on this table, and that what you state in your question that the you can't get the identity back during the INSERT only.  Then changing the SQL to this will do the trick for you.

```
$sql = ''
    . 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE sAMAccountName = ?) = 0 '
    . 'BEGIN '
    . 'INSERT INTO users (role, sAMAccountName, fullName) '
    . 'VALUES (1, ?, ?) '
    . 'END '
    . 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE sAMAccountName = ?';
```

Comment: A stored procedure isn't really an option for me. I'll have to just fire a completely separate SQL query in another connection if I can't get this to work. Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that since you are doing this in multiple locations in different applications a stored procedure is the only thing that actually makes sense. Hope you never have to change this since you have the same code now in several applications.

Comment: Changed the approach in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried all the above and can't get an ID on an insert. I'm now assuming the Microsoft SQL Driver for PHP is incapable and I had to go with a SQL Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out. Strip the extra single quotes and concatenations out and apply Dbloch's suggestion.

```
$sql = 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE sAMAccountName = ?) = 0
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO users (role, sAMAccountName, fullName)
            VALUES (1, ?, ?) 
            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id
            END
            ELSE SELECT id FROM users WHERE sAMAccountName = ?';
```

Comment: +1 It's hard to believe that SQL Server Management Studio can run such a one-liner flawlessly. I'm sure the posted code is actually missing separators, either carriage returns or semicolons.

Comment: Has to be, I tested it in SSMS myself and it worked perfectly.